# while installing dependencies from the repo its giving me error

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

here are the dependencies required to run this simple repository on my mac book for tiny face detection in python and it's giving me errors while installing the requirements.txt file
here is the error :

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - torchvision==0.3
  - pyclust==0.2.0
  - prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
  - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  - torch==1.1.0
  - pyclustering==0.8.1
Current channels:
```

I'm using conda env for this and python 3.7 I'm using for PyTorch
here is the URL of the repo: https://github.com/varunagrawal/tiny-faces-pytorch

i tried to install in a it again and again and follow the steps :
I used the "git clone" command to clone the repository.

I installed the necessary dependencies using the appropriate package manager.

However, I am still encountering the following error

Comment: could you please elaborate on using the "appropriate package manager"

Comment: may you please explain in a lil bit detail what should i do ?